# Can D3 library be used with the Electron (Atom shell)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, electron

Electron's website says that the applications made with electron can have access to node modules. Can they have access to the D3 library? If so, how can it be set up?

Answer (score 11):

D3 is available as a [Node.js module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3) that can be imported into the JavaScript code you want to use to render your visualisation application.

As an example of how to integrate D3 into an Electron application, have a look at my [D3 Space Filler Explorer](https://github.com/UsabilityEtc/d3-space-filler-explorer) application on GitHub. This application visualises disk space use with multiple D3 pie charts and a D3 treemap.

One pattern I found useful was to inject the SVG element into the D3 visualisation, which differs from the usual approach in D3 examples which creates the SVG element in the visualisation. See examples of this dependency injection in the /app/js/pie-chart.js and /app/js/treemap-chart.js files.

Comment: Did you run into some problems adding SVG using d3 ? Is that why you put it in the markup rather than create it with d3 ?

Comment: Either approach works fine. However, I think it's good design practice to inject the SVG element into the code that populates that SVG element to render a D3 chart. This has two benefits: (1) The rendering code is focused on rendering the chart without needing to know where in the HTML document the chart is placed. (2) The chart rendering code can be reused more easily in the same HTML document. For example, the D3 Space Filler Explorer has one pie chart per disk. To render multiple disk pie charts, one SVG element is created for each disk, which is passed into the pie chart rendering code.

Comment: At first I was creating the svg element using d3, but for some reason it absolutely would not create anything. Putting it in html and selecting it is the only way it would work for me.

I would actually prefer to create the svg(s) myself because then a component can just be given an html element id to display itself inside and the markup doesn't need to keep compliant to the component's internal requirements.

Comment: Hey man, ty for sharing your project. Unfortunately it isn't working. `npm start` gives error "Cannot find module app". Do you know why?

Comment: I'm not sure why the app module cannot be found. I've just cloned the repo, done an `npm install` and then `npm start` runs the app as expected. I'm using macOS Sierra (10.12.2).

Answer (score 2):

All (at least theoretically) pure JS modules are compatible with electron, since it also provides a (CommonJS) javascript runtime environment (io.js).

The only important thing is that electron doesn't automatically sets the `NODE_PATH` variable and doesn't look in system/global modules path for `require`d modules. So you just have to make sure that you have the path to `d3.js` on your `NODE_PATH`:

```
NODE_PATH="/PATH/TO/d3.js" electron /PATH/TO/APP
```

Answer (score 2):

We solved this in our workteam installing d3 with Npm:

`npm install d3 --save`

and in index.html we put this:

`<script>var d3 = require("d3")</script>`

We were getting this issue from nv.d3.js line 18, there is a little function requiring d3 as a node module and in our app we were using it in bower_components, so installing it with npm and requesting in your index directly from node_modules like as I said will probably solve this issue as it did with us.