# D3.js not defined with Electron

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, electron

I am trying to pass on Electron my AngularJS application based on D3.js. The application works perfectly when I try it with Chrmoium but when I try it on Electron, I have the error ReferenceError: d3 is not defined.
This is the declaration of the D3 :

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Even if I declare it in local, it doesn't works.

**Edit :** So, this is the solution. Install D3 and jsdom as node module.

```
npm install d3
npm install jsdom
```

Just add this in the HTML instead of `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`:

```
<script>
    var d3 = require("d3"),
    jsdom = require("jsdom");

    var document = jsdom.jsdom(),
    svg = d3.select(document.body).append("svg");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can actually use D3.js as a node module, which should solve your issues. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774237/can-d3-library-be-used-with-the-electron-atom-shell) for instructions.
[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3) is the NPM page for it.