# Using D3 with Electron React app

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, electron

I'm building an app using electron with electron-react-boilerplate found here  https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate.git , it's all working fine.

But when I am trying to use D3, electron always throws me the error `zTypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined.  (ie : console.log(d3.version) )`.

- I followed the instructions found here: [Can D3 library be used with the Electron (Atom shell)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774237/can-d3-library-be-used-with-the-electron-atom-shell), with no result.
- I added script (https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js) to `index.html`, with no result.
- The same issue with `<script>var d3 = require("d3")</script>`.

My Config:

- Electron 1.4.15
- Chromium 53.0.2785.143
- node@6.9.4 | win32 | x64
- react 15.4.2
- d3 4.5.0

I hope someone can help with this issue.

Comment: If you're using the latest version of electron-react-boilerplate, shouldn't you be adding the `<script>var d3 = require("d3")</script>` to app.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply use `var d3 = require('d3');` at the top of any jsx file that requires d3. This works for both of the electron + d3 based apps that I am currently working on.

Comment: Thank you, man, your answer is right and it's all working fine.

Comment: Glad it worked out. I should mention that certain libraries I require in this manner are not available in the chrome debugger namespace even though they are internally available for use within the context of each js/jsx file in which they are imported. For those libraries, I add in `window.d3 = d3;` so that they are available in the console debugger for easy testing/prototyping. I believe d3 doesn't require this as the way its exports are handled results in it being available by default in the global namespace, but this is handy for other libraries where this may not be the case